# Ghost (Node blogging engine): Is there any way to log failed login attempts?

Tags: security, nginx, brute-force, ghost, fail2ban

Ghost admins!

I'd like to protect a Ghost blog from possible **brute-force** login attacks.

1. Is there any way to **log failed user login attempts** with **Ghost**?

I looked for logs everywhere and didn't find much of anything. (Running on **Nginx**/**Linux** server. ). Are these failed login attempts even **logged anywhere**?

2. Is it possible to **ban users** after multiple failed attempts?

Having **fail2ban** or other login protection isn't much good if someone can attempt to **brute-force** your admin logins.

Answer (score 0):

Ghost already implements two types of login restrictions that I can see:

- Account-level lockout on 5 failed login attempts ([Github issue](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/499) and [code](https://github.com/javorszky/Ghost/commit/368eb7a3526eff3460d65355c8741f3d8eca0b44))
- IP-level login attempt throttling - max of one login attempt per 2 seconds ([Github issue](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/468) and [code](https://github.com/javorszky/Ghost/commit/368eb7a3526eff3460d65355c8741f3d8eca0b44))

These should be reasonably secure; implementing fail2ban on top of this may provide diminishing returns - but if you want to, failed logins appear to generate a 404 error like the following in `/var/log/nginx/access.log`, which shouldn't be hard to set up in fail2ban using rules like [this](http://envyandroid.com/fail2ban-wordpress-login-attacks/).

```
1.2.3.4 - - [10/Mar/2018:00:48:51 +0000] "POST /ghost/api/v0.1/authentication/token HTTP/2.0" 404 366 "http://blog.example.com/ghost/" "[user-agent]"
```